# Downloaded OSBuddy from website which opened Ubuntu Software Center and proceeded to download. It now won't launch.

Tags: xfce, crouton

Went on RSbuddy.com, downloaded the .deb file. It opened Ubuntu Software Center, then it proceeded to download. I then opened applications menu then games and then clicked OSBuddy.... and nothing happened.

I'm using crouton, xfce, trusty if that helps.

I really new at this.

Comment: Either run the Updates app or, in terminal, fully update your OS with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` *before* using the software center (Ubuntu Software).

Answer (score 0):

So, I couldn't figure out .deb, but I got the .jar file to work instead with java -jar OSBuddy.jar after restarting the chromebook. Thanks